# Deleting directory and refreshing

Tags: java

I deleted a directory through Java program.The directory is deleted but the memory is not released completely.The temporary file is still there and clicking on refresh it gets deleted completely.So,is there is any mechanism to refresh automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Just because it shows in Windows Explorer doesn't mean it hasn't been deleted. Pressing "Refresh" only refreshes the GUI - if the file is gone after the refresh, it was *already* deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The file is actually deleted from the file system and there is some delay in refreshing the windows explorer.

Although its not necessary to do but still in order to refresh the file explorer through the program you should explorer the source code of Tortoise SVN. It is written in C++ and uses Windows native API. You will not be able to reuse it as it is, but can extract the idea from there.

Source codes for your concern are as below:

- [TortoiseCVS - ShellUtils.cpp](http://tortoisecvs.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tortoisecvs/TortoiseCVS/src/Utils/ShellUtils.cpp?revision=1.70&view=markup&pathrev=MAIN)
- [TortoiseSVN - ShellUpdater.cpp](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/svn/tortoisesvn/trunk/src/Utils/ShellUpdater.cpp) (username: "guest", password: "")

How Tortoise does it?

- set the shell icon size or colour depth to a temporary value
- updates all the windows by broadcasting the setting change
- resets the shell icon size or colour depth to the original value
- updates all the windows a second time with a broadcast of the setting change

This may be the complex mechanism to do so, but, unfortunately, there isn't any easy way out of this.

My suggestion: Just delete the file from Java and let file system handle it itself.

Shishir